# Width of Winform datagridview column not obeying width set for it

Tags: winforms, datagridview

I am setting the width of a WinForm datagridview column to 140 and I am checking the width and it's 100. The grid is wide enough to make all columns wider. Why isn't the column accepting the 140 value? Is there a setting which controls the max width?

```
MyGrid.Columns["Name"].Width = 140;
int i = MyGrid.Columns["Name"].Width; //why is i = 100?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the `MyGrid.Columns["Name"].AutoSizeMode`, set it to `DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.NotSet`

```
MyGrid.Columns["Name"].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.NotSet;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
da.Fill(dtable);
                    dgvCategory.DataSource = dtable;
                    dgvCategory.Columns["Category"].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.NotSet;
                    dgvCategory.Columns["Category"].Width=150;
                    dgvCategory.Columns["MainCat"].Width = 180;
```